# Is there a Cohuman client?

Tags: software-recommendation, client

Simple question: Does someone know a client for the GTD webservice [Cohuman](http://www.cohuman.com) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no one has previously answered your question. The answer is very simply no.